# Java: Getting properties from Set<>

Tags: java, hibernate, object, set, restrictions

I am using [org.hibernate.criterion Class Restrictions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) to add restrictions on what is returned from a search.

Just a bit of information, I have a object `Person` which has a property `Set<LevelPassed>`. `LevelPassed` is an object with the property `level` which is what I want to return.

I am trying to use `Restrictions.in(String, Object[])` but the problem I am encountering is that for the string I am returning a `Set<LevelPassed>` and not a `LevelPassed`. This means that I am unable to get the levels passed of each using the following `Restrictions.in("levelsPassed.level", Object[])`

So the question is does anyone know a way to check all the `LevelPassed` in the `Set<LevelPassed>` using a string property that Restrictions.in() uses